# How to create a new user in a Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, user, new

I am trying to create a new user in sandbox.

I have admin access to the production org.

When I click on *Log In* link from the list of Sandboxes, it takes me to the new login page, but I do not have user id for the sandbox. How do I access it?

Answer (score 2):

Your *username* is the same as production with the name of the sandbox appended to the end of it after a period (.)

Your *password* is the same as production.

Example:

- Production username = frank@frankcompany.com
- Sandbox name = TestEnv
- **Sandbox username** = frank@frankcompany.com.testenv